# LSASS.exe trying to communicate over port 80

Tags: security, http, port-80, lsass

We are running a standalone web server (Windows 2008 + IIS 7), and our antivirus is blocking LSASS.exe (C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe) from making outbound connections over port 80.

Why is LSASS doing this? (Should I be worried?)

Comment: I just witnessed the same thing happening upon initiation of an outgoing RDP session.  lsass.exe was trying to connect over port 80 to the same server that I was connecting to via RDP.  I would not worry about the possibility that it is a virus, but I would really like to know what the #@&k is lsass.exe trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

You should run a virus check and see what turns up.  Try a few different ones to be sure.